# Why do I get a error date value?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, android-calendar

I use the following code to display the details of a photo, but I find the value of  myInfo.date is 22:15 15-01-1970.
What error do I made? Thanks!

```
public static void GetPhotoDetailsByID(Context mycontext,String id,DetailsInfo myInfo )      {
         Cursor cur = mycontext.getContentResolver().query(
                 MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                 null,
                 MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+"=?", 
                 new String[]{id},
                 "" );
         if (cur.moveToFirst()){
             myInfo.title= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
             myInfo.path = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
             myInfo.size=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));
             myInfo.date=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED));
             myInfo.date=GetDate(mycontext,myInfo.date);

             /*
             myInfo.resolution=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH))
                               +" x "
                               +cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT));
             */

             myInfo.thumbnails = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                               mycontext.getContentResolver(), 
                               Integer.parseInt(id),
                               MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, 
                               null);

         }
         cur.close();
    }

private static String GetDate(Context mycontext,String date){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now =Long.parseLong(date)  ;
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(now);
    Date myDate = calendar.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy");
    return sdf.format(myDate);
}
```

Comment: And what should your date looks like ?

Comment: I guess these pictures were not taken in 1970...

Comment: Can you print `String date` you are passing in `getDate` method?

Comment: How do you know the date is not `1970` ? You have not mentioned what date you expect ? Without that how will people answer your Qs properly ? Rephrase your question, properly and give better explanations as to what you expect .

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is to multiply by 1000 :

```
Date date=new Date(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED))*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need calendar,

you could do Date myDate = new Date(now);
What is the value of now ?

Comment: private static String GetDate(Context mycontext,String date){

Answer (score 0):

**android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED**

provide the time that was last modified but since 1970 and the unit of time is seconds. so you have to do a mathematics and calculate the date and time of that images.

you can check android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATE_MODIFIED) for references

you can get Last modified date of file as follow

```
File file = new File("Your file path");
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```